# iOS 6 MSTag common_button_done issue

Tags: ios6

When scanning an `MSTag`, the "Done" button displays "common_button_done" on the `MSTag` scan result view.  This is occurring on iOS 6, but does not happen when running the app on iOS 5.1.1. We are using the `MSTag` SDK version with release date: `9/25/2012` (latest as of today).

I haven't been able to find anything regarding this issue.  It seems that there maybe some localization file that can't be found or read for whatever reason, when running on iOS 6.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the Library Search Paths are correct and that an old copy of the SDK is not hanging around from your version control system.  In my case, an old copy was still being pulled down from CVS to a different location, and there were Library Search Path entries still there for the old copy--which was not referenced any longer by the project.

I removed the old copy from CVS, removed the old Library Search Path entries, nested the updated SDK in a different folder--to make sure the latest files were added to CVS, and added the correct Library Search Path entries.

For some reason, MSTagCoreResources.bundle was not being detected by CVS as having been updated--thus not getting check in, thus getting overwritten with the next "Get Latest"...thus not getting updated on all the developer machines.